# Silent shutdown reading CSV file

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm currently building a backend application using a microservice architecture.
One of my services is an apache spark job runner which uses Apache Spark & Kafka to receive a message with a date range and extract some data from a CSV file in that date range.

This is the full code of my service, I've put everything into the main and changes the `processMarketDataRequest` method to something more simple like getting the avg price for all the logs in the CSV file for simplicity reasons (so please overlook the unused variable `request`):

```java
package com.samurai.lab.sparkjobservice;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App2 {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final String KAFKA_BROKERS = "localhost:9092";
    private static final String KAFKA_GROUP = "sparkGroup";
    private static final String KAFKA_TOPIC = "marketDataRequests";
    private static final String MARKETDATA_CSV_PATH = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/TickData/data-12-01-until-12-03-year-2020/fake.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(App2::consume);
    }

    private static void consume() {
        try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = createKafkaConsumer()) {
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(KAFKA_TOPIC));

            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    processRecord(record);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static KafkaConsumer<String, String> createKafkaConsumer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BROKERS);
        props.put("group.id", KAFKA_GROUP);
        props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    }

    private static void processRecord(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
            try {
                String jsonMessage = record.value();
                JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonMessage);

                processMarketDataRequest(rootNode);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while processing record: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private static void processMarketDataRequest(JsonNode request) {
        // Create a Spark session
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("ClientModeExample")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        // Check if file exists
        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(MARKETDATA_CSV_PATH))) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist: " + MARKETDATA_CSV_PATH);
            return;
        }

        // Read CSV into a DataFrame
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv(MARKETDATA_CSV_PATH);

        // Convert the Price column to double
        Dataset<Row> dfDouble = df.withColumn("Price", df.col("Price").cast("double"));

        // Calculate the average price
        Dataset<Row> avgPrice = dfDouble.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg("Price").alias("average_price"));

        // Print the average price
        avgPrice.show();

        // Stop the Spark session
        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

This is the full log details from the console:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J: Found provider [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@620b29e6]
SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider@121ff335]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@620b29e6]
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
23/07/21 13:00:36 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.4.1
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: ClientModeExample
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: USER
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: USER
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: USER; groups with view permissions: EMPTY; users with modify permissions: USER; groups with modify permissions: EMPTY
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 5396.
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-sparkGroup-1, groupId=sparkGroup] Revoke previously assigned partitions marketDataRequests-0
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-sparkGroup-1, groupId=sparkGroup] Member consumer-sparkGroup-1-89cbdb45-88a1-4d93-9817-26920020efe5 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator DESKTOP-SCGERG2.lan:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-sparkGroup-1, groupId=sparkGroup] Resetting generation and member id due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-sparkGroup-1, groupId=sparkGroup] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO Metrics: Metrics scheduler closed
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO Metrics: Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO Metrics: Metrics reporters closed
23/07/21 13:00:37 INFO AppInfoParser: App info kafka.consumer for consumer-sparkGroup-1 unregistered

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So basically as you can see I'm experiencing a silent shutdown of the process, nothing in the log output indicates an error it simply closes and I'm trying to understand why?

Any insights on how can I find the error or fix this issue would be welcomed.

Here is the pom.xml for reference:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.samurai.lab</groupId>
        <artifactId>samurai-lab</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spark-job-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spark-job-service</name>
    <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <apache-spark.version>3.4.1</apache-spark.version>
        <apache-kafka.version>3.5.0</apache-kafka.version>
        <extraJavaTestArgs>
            -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED
            -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false
        </extraJavaTestArgs>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to use `printStackTrace` in your exception handler except for throwaway example code. Just let the exception escape the method. Then you'll see the stack trace in your log. As you have it now, there is a stack trace printed _somewhere_ (or possibly nowhere), but it's not in the log.

Comment: Thanks, it help a lot, I saw the error printing out after removing it, was missing configuration, and the Scala version incorrect

Comment: FWIW, you don't really need Spark to read and average a CSV file. Just open the file with a regular CSV library and iterate over it. Or at the very least, you should use Spark Kafka consumer rather than use plain Kafka client API

Comment: @OneCricketeer I gave the average as a small example because it was not the root of my problem, the real usage is heavy (creating market data from the futures market order book log)

Comment: Still, if you're only reading a local file on disk, you won't need Spark... It is outputting data, but in the Spark UI, in the executor logs... You're looking at logs of the driver app